# update command denied to user for insert on duplicate key update

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I am trying to use insert on duplicate key update in MySQL 8 like this:

```
INSERT INTO orders SELECT * FROM temporary_orders ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE column1='a';
```

But I get this error:

```
UPDATE command denied to user 'user'@'localhost' for column 'column1' in table 'orders';
```

Initially my user only had `SELECT` and `UPDATE` privileges, but now I gave the user global privileges and the error still occurs. Running:

```
INSERT INTO orders SELECT * FROM temporary_orders;
```

Works without the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` portion. I am also able to run:

```
UPDATE orders SET column1='a';
```

My specific MySQL version is `mysql  Ver 8.0.16 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)`.

I ran this command to give my user global privileges:

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'user'@'localhost';
```

And running:

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'user'@'localhost';
```

Outputs:

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, RELOAD, SHUTDOWN, PROCESS, FILE, REFERENCES, INDEX, ALTER, SHOW DATABASES, SUPER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE, REPLICATION SLAVE, REPLICATION CLIENT, CREATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW, CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE, CREATE USER, EVENT, TRIGGER, CREATE TABLESPACE, CREATE ROLE, DROP ROLE ON *.* TO `user`@`localhost`
```

**UPDATE**

I've tested and using the root user does work, but I'm not sure what permission could be missing.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a new user and then granting all permissions like so:

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'user'@'localhost';
```

And it worked fine. Not sure what the problem was.